# Grails: Should I use a controller or javascript to run queries and update the page accordingly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, grails, controller

I am fairly new to Grails and Frameworks in general. I'm trying to program a little webshop in which you can select a category and subcategories of products (select element and checkboxes) which are then requested via sql and displayed. 
My problem is that both the categories and subcategories are also tables in my database. This means that I cannot hardcode controller actions rendering a specific view for every category. Should I do all that with jquery and ajax and stay in one view?
Or should I use the same controller action for everything? That would result in a strange reloading of the view every time the selection is changed. 
I guess that this is a rather stupid question resulting from lack of knowledge about the framework in general but I really am stuck and would be very thankful if someone could help me.

Thanks already!
Alex

Comment: the best way is how your logic will always be, for example in a controller cear actions to load categories and subcategories, return them as json or an array of the way that suits you and manipulate them in the view probably through javascript It is difficult to give you a observation without a specific case or question

Comment: @user615274 Thanks a lot already. I was aware of the fact that my question wasn't asked in a very concise way, but really didn't manage to make it sound less generalized. I am going to try to follow your suggested procedure and maybe return with a more precise question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

javascript is mainly used for your frontend. Use it for accessing your API on your backend, not for replacing your controllers.